# IEnumerable.Intersect does not return all values that match

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have two Lists `List<MyClass>`:

```
public class MyClass : IEquatable<MyClass>
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int AccountType { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MyClass other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;
        return AccountNumber.Equals(other.AccountNumber) && AccountType.Equals(other.AccountType);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashAccountNumber = AccountNumber == null ? 0 : AccountNumber.GetHashCode();
        int hashType = AccountType.GetHashCode();
        return hashAccountNumber ^ hashType;
    }
}
```

If I use the following code

```
var list1 = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass() { AccountNumber = "1", AccountType = 1, ID = 1}, 
    new MyClass() { AccountNumber = "1", AccountType = 1, ID = 2},
    new MyClass() { AccountNumber = "2", AccountType = 1, ID = 3},
    new MyClass() { AccountNumber = "3", AccountType = 1, ID = 4}
};

var list2 = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass() { AccountNumber = "1", AccountType = 1, ID = 1 }
};

var alist = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

`alist` only has 1 element where `MyClass.ID == 1`. It does not return the second one that also matches. I can do it the other way around as well `var alist = list2.Intersect(list1).ToList();` and I get the same result

**Is there something wrong with my `IEquatable` implementation? Because I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Or is this just the way `IEnumerable` works? Is there another way I can use to return ALL matching elements from list1? I really hope there is :)**

Comment: Side note: If you're implementing `IEquatable<T>` and overriding `GetHashCode`, you ought to also be overriding `Equals(object other)`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I cannot override `Equals`. `Error 1 'MyClass.Equals(MyClass)': no suitable method found to override` when I add override to it. Should'nt I override `Equals` it if I use the same signature of `IEquatable`? Instead I've used the class type and therefor I've overloaded Equals with the class type. If you think it is not correct, please let me know.

Comment: You should have *two* Equals methods - one accepting a `MyClass` which  you currently have. The *other* should be an override of the `Object.Equals(Object)` method. See the example in the documentation for [IEquatable.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Jaques BTW I feel that your question is an XY problem. I can't understand why an intersection shouldn't work for you. Why you want two occurences of the same object?

Comment: Because the objects is not 100% the same. I have a shortened version of the class. Only 2 properties is used to see if it is the same kind of object, but the other properties makes it unique. And I want them all in the one list because  of how I have to built the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other guys have already said, `Intersect` will always return list of **distinct** elements that are on both sets.

To achieve what you want, try changing `Intersect` with this:

```
var alist = list1.Where(x => list2.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. At least you answered the question and not just told me it can't happen.

Comment: @Jaques No one has told *it can't happen* but your question title and body is about intersections. As I said in my own answer in some comment, you should ask another question if you think that your current one doesn't fit what you're looking for...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Question was there from the very beginning. _Is there another way I can use to return ALL matching elements from list1?_ Read whole thing, not just title.

Comment: @KasparsOzols Yeah, btw, I can't understand why someone throws dozens of lines to ask why an intersection doesn't work like OP wants, and in the last sentence, asks a very different question.

Comment: Your answer is what I was looking for. I gave a problem statement int he title, And asked for help. You gave it to me. My Title and body is my problem that I have with Intersections. And I asked if there is another way my problem can be solved.

Comment: @KasparsOzols Q title: **IEnumerable.Intersect does not return all values that match**...

Answer (score 4):

An intersection is a *set operation* (*set* understood as data structure!), thus, I don't see why your result should contain the same item twice. A set is a collection of unique elements.

Comment: Thanks, I asked if there is a solution for this. Obviously my approach is not correct then, is there another?

Comment: @Jaques Then ask another question. You're asking if your intersection is done wrongly, while it is done as expected... I would ask another question explaining what you want to achieve in your domain.

Comment: @Marias `Is there another way I can use to return ALL matching elements from list1? I really hope there is :)`

Comment: I didn't change the meaning of my question. My Question title described my problem. I asked the question in the body. You didn't read the question.

Comment: @Jaques I've read the question, and it was about why intersect returns one item instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Intersect enumerates *first*, collecting all **distinct** elements of that sequence. It then enumerates *second*, marking those elements that occur in both sequences. Finally, the marked elements are yielded in the order in which they were collected.

Comment: Thanks, I asked if there is a solution for this. Obviously my approach is not correct then, is there another?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, with this code your Equals method is not wasted:

```
var alist = list1.Where(m => list2.Any(n => n.Equals(m)));
```